# Where did the iAds Network page go?

Tags: development, app-store-connect

Good day,

Apple has just came up with this new iAds Networks workbench where you can create your own campaign for promoting your app. This button appears instead of the old one (iAds Network) in iTunes connect in the developer's main page.

My question is where is the original iAds Network page from which you could track your iAds Network status (requests,imperessions, revenue etc...) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems it is gone.
try this to get it back:
https://iad.apple.com/itcportal/

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.